# How do I programmatically generate something like /proc/pid/maps?

Tags: c, linux

How do I programmatically generate something like /proc/pid/maps ?
Is there an API which can get me the same data as in /proc/pid/maps ?
Parsing text can be a bit flaky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/proc/$pid/maps` **is** the API. If you're using C, you can reliably parse lines in this file using the `scanf` format:

```
"%08lx-%08lx %c%c%c%c %08llx %02x:%02x %lu %n"
```

([source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=fs/proc/task_mmu.c;h=4540b8f76f163fbaaef250b6facf161424a90869;hb=28a33cbc24e4256c143dce96c7d93bf423229f92#l242))

Comment: That only works for 32-bit. `printf` has a _minimum_ field width, while `scanf` has a _maximum_ field width. For 64-bit: s/08/16/g